# Difference between 打算, 安排 and 计划?

Tags: word-choice

So, I understand from other posts that 打算 is plan in the sense of ‘intend’, i.e. the details of the plan aren't yet finalised, while 计划 is more formalised such that the details of the plan are relatively fixed.

My question is therefore: how does 安排 fit into this?! Is this 'plan' more 打算, more 计划, or something completely different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

安排 means *arrange or arrangement*, a verb or a noun. For example, 安排你们住下 means arrange your lodging.

计划 and 打算 are as you said.

Comment: Oh Dan, you are on fire! Thanks again :-)

Comment: Delete me, This girl is on fire.